# Software to convert JPG images into specific file size on disk?

Tags: windows, software-rec, jpeg

Is there any (free?) software that will help me to convert existing JPG files into a specific file size on disk?

(I assume that the software will estimate accurately compressed file size during the save.)

Comment: A "certain size" as in pixel dimensions or as in file size?

Comment: I'd say file size, @Mokubai, given the reference to compression.

Comment: do you want to create dummy files, or *convert* existing files into files of a specific disk size?

Comment: convert existing. file size on disk

Comment: (Next time please note the "edit" link. Thanks and success!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) is pretty good and does it for jpeg- just install it WITH the plugins and setting file size should be a save option. I quite like Irfanview in fact, it's light, easy, quick and does batch operations nicely :)

Answer (score 5):

The command line ImageMagick [supports](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define) a maximum file size:

```
-define jpeg:extent=400kb
```

Answer (score 2):

[Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net/) gives the file size when saving:

[image: Show file size on saving]

Simply change the quality setting to get the size you want.

Answer (score 1):

For quick and easy image resize I always use and recommend Picture-Resize. It's very easy to use and blazing fast.

http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize

It does not have a GUI, you just change the filename in order to change the parameters of the image resize operation. A very unusual but cool way to operate.

Comment: The question seems to be asking about file-size not image dimensions

Comment: yep, it's about file size, not dimensions

Comment: you can do a file size resize with the program I mentioned

Comment: Upvote because this program is one of the most versatile applications to perform *batch* image resize. For some operations irfanview is quite overkill. This program is specially good for sending it to family; for example the program application PhotoResizeK1000NMROEH.exe will resize images to 1000KB preserving everything. The user will only have to place it in the desktop and drag/drop the pictures or folders to convert. It does not get easier than that (in the webpage the program settings can be configured)

Answer (score 0):

Irfanview with the Save-for-Web plugin does this.

1. [Install irfanview](http://www.irfanview.net/main_download_engl.htm).
2. Install and download the plugin. The recommended way to do this is to just download and install the ["All plugins" package](http://www.irfanview.net/plugins.htm) from their website.

In irfanView, the plugin is accessible via "File", "Save for web (plugin)". There's a "Compress for size" option that lets you enter a desired file size and then makes an approximation of what you entered.